# Physical effects on light from stars

Tags: visible-light, astronomy

I was thinking about how we see stars at a distance, the light that travels from them is affected by the Earths atmosphere, gravitational lensing and dust etc., but there doesn't appear any equation that allows for the expansion of space itself, surely this would have an effect on light travelling through it, and if not, why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expansion of space due to "[inflation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_%28cosmology%29)" is considered to be the cause of significant redshifts that is observed. It is sometimes referred to as a "[Cosmological redshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redshift#Expansion_of_space)", and is described with the appropriate equations.

Comment: I was more thinking about expansion along the z axis though and it altering the direction the light is traveling slightly, or is the expansion equal throughout all space in which case the expansion would just disperse the light

Comment: Space expands in all places and in all directions, equally.

Comment: Downvoted. Cosmological expansion and inflation are not the same thing. Inflation happened way before any currently visible photons were emitted, and any photon emitted before or during inflatio would be redshifted so much and its energy so low it would be for all practical purposes impossible to detect.